# Stock Intel CPU/Heatsink - same part number, different manufacturer, different amperage?

Tags: heatsink, intel-core-i3

I'm looking to replace my Core i3-6100 heatsink/fan with another stock Intel one.  The one I have now has a vibration that I can't isolate.  I'm only interested in the push-pin style and it pretty much seems that Intel heatsinks are the only type that have it.

However, it appears that, as I'm shopping around, there are a lot of different manufacturers I found on Amazon for the same E97379-003 part.

```
Nidec = 0.18A
Delta = 0.60A <= This is the one I currently have
Foxconn = 0.20A
```

There may be others I haven't come across.

I'm not sure why the one I have is over 3x the amperage of the others, but I want to avoid buying the Delta manufactured part in case the vibration issue is related to them.

I have another Intel build with a Core i5-6500 and E97379-001 Foxconn 0.17A, which is pretty dang quiet.

Is it ok to use any E97379 heatsink for Core i3-6100 regardless of the revision(?) (001 or 003) and amperage?

Comment: Perhaps the extra amps is to overcome the friction that's causing the vibration? ;-) Doubt it, but that certainly would either increase it's current draw, or decrease its rotational speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the heatsink can handle the TDP of the CPU (51W) and it supports the socket (LGA1151) you can use any type of heatsink.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it'd be perfectly fine.  I've used different generation Intel stock heaksinks (one from a Celeron G1820 LGA 1150 socket for an i7-6700k on the LGA 1151 socket) and it worked perfectly fine.

I also want to add that because you're already using the E97379 on the i5-6500 (assuming temperatures and noise are fine), I would assume the E97379 cooling the 65W TDP i5-6500 would work more than adequately with the i3-6100 at 51W TDP.